# Is there a way to automatically propose a commit message regarding to new submodule commits?

Tags: git

I'm using a library (say `foo`) in my projects and `foo` uses another library (say `bar`) where I'm also the maintainer of `foo` and `bar`.

When I change something in `bar` library, I commit the changes in `bar` repository with appropriate commit message. However, duplicating that appropriate message in `foo` and `myproject` is very frustrating so I just commit the changes with `update bar` and `update foo` messages respectively.

How can I make the `git commit` command to propose me the latest submodule commit messages?

Comment: Write a small shell script which does `git log --pretty=format:%s` on the commit range you get from `git diff bar`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck [`git diff --submodule bar`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---submoduleltformatgt)

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of hacky, but here is a way to commit the submodule change in  the superproject using the same commit message as the latest submodule commit (assuming you are using Bash):

```bash
GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES=.git/modules/<submodule-name>/objects git commit -C $(git -C path/to/submodule log --format=%h -1)
```

This runs `git log` in the submodule to get the hash of the latest commit, and then uses [`GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITALTERNATEOBJECTDIRECTORIEScode) to temporarily add the submodule object directory as an alternate to the superproject, such that Git can go read the submodule commit message and use it for the superproject commit.

Answer (score -1):

You would not need to duplicate anything if `bar` was declared as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** inside `foo` repository.

```bash
cd /path/to/foo
git submodule add /url/to/bar
cd bar
# add and commit with proper message
git push
cd ..
git add bar
git commit -m "update bar"
```

The point is: you don't need to duplicate bar commit message, since the very `bar` repository is in `foo`, and you can directly see the `bar` file history, with its original commit message, in `foo/bar`.